# add project to current one

Tags: ios, cocoa

I found a feedback app's source code and I would like to know how can I add that project to my current one?

So that the feedback app opens in my current app when I press a button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_Project_to_a_Workspace.html):

1. In the project navigator, Control-click in the empty space below the list.
2. Choose Add Files to “\<Workspace_Name>”.
3. Navigate into the folder containing the .xcodeproj file to add.
4. Select the .xcodeproj file and click Add.

[image]

Comment: Just tried that but when I try to build the app it gives me about 1 warning and 6 errors

Comment: @belcinify:If you can't understand / fix those warnings and errors then you can create a new question asking for help for them specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add another project and get its app opened from your app by pressing a button. You will need to,add the code to your app.